# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'Zu', but it was: a custom ea object

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from firestore and show it in the frontend. But I keep getting this error "Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'Zu', but it was: a custom ea object"
Code:[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynZl1.png)

Error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hs3h.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getDocs` instead of `getDoc` when querying multiple documents from a collection.